# How do I set the colour of an active item in the menu bar using NativeScript?

Tags: css, nativescript, menubar

I would like to change the colour of a menu item in the menu bar based on which one is selected. So when "Home" is selected I would like it to be red and all the other items to be black. When I select "Settings" it should become red and all the other items should be black. I tried this [in the NativeScript Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Q0LVeG), but wasn't able to get it working.

**HTML**

```
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal" class="foot" backgroundColor="#eae8e8" padding="10 5 10 5" id="myMenu" [ngClass]="{ 'active': itemActive }">
        <StackLayout (tap)="gofp()" width="30%" textAlignment="center">
            <Label text="Home">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout (tap)="gosettings()" width="35%" textAlignment="center">
            <Label  text="Settings">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout (tap)="goimages()" width="35%" textAlignment="center">
            <Label text="Images">
            </Label>
              </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the labels of the menu items? If so then there are several ways to do so, you can either do it directly using `style.color` on the `<Label>` element or you can use a CSS class (`class="name-of-class"`).

So in practice:

```
<Label text="Home" style.color="red"></Label>
```

Or:

```
<Label text="Home" class="color--red"></Label>

// In your CSS file
.color--red {
  color: red;
}
```

---

If you want to change the colour of the labels based on what is selected, you will need to add some logic. Let's start with the easiest thing.

**CSS**

```
.color--red {
    color: red;
}
```

Then you need to add some logic to actually track which menu item is selected. In your `home.component.ts` add the following before the constructor: `selectedMenuItemId: string;`, in your constructor add `this.selectedMenuItemId = "home";` and after your constructor add:

```
public selectMenuItem(id: string) {
  this.selectedMenuItemId = id;
}
```

And then for every menu item, you need to first replace the tap handler with the following: `(tap)="selectMenuItem('home')"` and add the following to every menu label: `[ngClass]="{'color--red': selectedMenuItemId === 'home'}"`, make sure to change the id's.

[Here is a link to the Nativescript Playground with the changes.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Q0LVeG&v=2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want something like in this image: https://www.google.al/search?biw=1920&bih=974&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=6Zd1W_P3NomQmwX8sLeoBQ&q=how+to+change+text+color+menu+in+nativescript&oq=how+to+change+text+color+menu+in+nativescript&gs_l=img.3...8629.20031.0.20277.29.26.3.0.0.0.120.2582.17j9.26.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.7.556...0j0i8i30k1j0i24k1j0i67k1j0i30k1j35i39k1.0.Rg1pgGK8awk#imgdii=sAnzA0dvAfsEnM:&imgrc=Cf7DOssb2IfYWM: